# How to get rid of search parameter in URL in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-parameters

I have a link that will be emailed to my users. The link is of the form `http://mysite.com/#/somePage?myParam=123`.

When this page is accessed I read the value of `myParam` by accessing `$routeParams.myParam` in the controller. I send this value as part of a request to the server with the `$http` service, and if that generates a success response I redirect to `http://mysite.com/#/anotherPage`.

However, the search parameter remains in the URL, so I'm actually redirected to `http://mysite.com/#/anotherPage?myParam=123`. And if I continue to navigate my site the search parameter remains in the URL from this point on.

How can I remove it?

I've tried doing `delete $routeParams.myParam` before and after the redirect. I've tried doing `$location.search('myParam', null)` before and after the redirect. None of these works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution turned out to be to upgrade from Angular 1.0.5 to 1.0.6, as it was a bug in Angular.